# ¿Como puedo poner un final a la hora de hacer el ascenso de colina en un grafo?

Tags: python, while, pop

Hola buenas disculpen tengo un programa de un recorrido de un grafo que me pide el nodo de origen para empezar en donde comenzara ya que se basa en la lista del grafo que se muestra, pero lo que me pide un profesor es que tenga el nodo final que se muestre que si el elemento esta en la lista del grafo se muestre junto con el recorrido y que sino esta me lo vuelva a pedir nuevamente.

¿Me pueden ayudar?

```
import os
grafo = {'a': [('p',4), ('j',15), ('b',1)],
        'b': [('a',1), ('d',2), ('e',2), ('c',3)],
        'j': [('a',15)],
        'p': [('a', 4)],
        'd': [('b',2), ('g',3)],
        'e': [('b',2), ('g',4), ('f',5), ('c',2)],
        'c': [('b',3), ('e',2), ('f',5), ('i',20)],
        'g': [('d',3), ('e',4), ('f',10), ('h',1)],
        'f': [('g',10), ('e',5), ('c',5)],
        'i': [('c',20)],
        'h': [('g',1)] 
    }

#MUESTRA EL GRAFO ANTES DEL RECORRIDO
print("Muestra el grafo antes del recorrido: \n")
for key, lista in grafo.items():
  print(key)
  print(lista)

  print()
  os.system("pause")
    
visitados = []
cola = []

origen = input("\nIngresa el nodo origen: ")
print("\nLista de recorrido en anchura\n")
#Paso 1: SE COLOCA EL VÉRTICE ORIGEN EN UNA COLA
cola.append(origen)
#Paso 2: MIENTRAS LA COLA NO ESTE VACÍA
while cola:
#paso 3: DESENCOLAR UN VÉRTICE, ESTE SERÁ AHORA EL VÉRTICE ACTUAL
actual = cola.pop(0)

#paso 4: SI EL VÉRTICE ACTUAL NO HA SIDO VISITADO
if actual not in visitados:
    #paso 5: PROCESAR (IMPRIMIR) EL VÉRTICE ACTUAL
    indice = lista.index(final)
    print("Vertice actual -> ", actual)
    #paso 6: COLOCAR VÉRTICE ACTUAL EN LA LISTA DE VISITADOS
    visitados.append(actual)
#paso 7: PARA CADA VÉRTICE QUE EL VÉRTICE ACTUAL TIENE COMO DESTINO,
#        Y QUE NO HA SIDO VISITADO:
#        ENCOLAR EL VERTICE
for key, lista in grafo[actual]:
    if key not in visitados:
        cola.append(key)

print()
os.system("pause")
```

Muestra del codigo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que es lo que ocurre ahora mismo con tu código? En qué necesitas ayuda exactamente?

Comment: Ps que me sale el recorrido del arbol al poner el nodo de inicio pero me piden el nodo final si esta en la lista al ingresarla y si esta que se muestre el recorrido del principio y sino esta que vuelva a pedirlo

Comment: `if nodo in grafo:`