# ¿Como puedo poner los valores en un grafo en un programa para subir una colina?

Tags: python, json, bucle-for

Hola buenas tengo un problema un compañero me presento un programa de subir colina a través de grafos, pero por lo que veo sus funciones son algo complicadas de entender y quería ver si pueden ayudarme a entenderlo también, si esta bien, si hay funciones que no se necesitan y hacer que no dependa de la función random que sea a través de un grafo por el método json.

Este problema es muy parecido a una pregunta que hice hace mucho:
[¿Como puedo poner un final a la hora de hacer el ascenso de colina en un grafo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562519/como-puedo-poner-un-final-a-la-hora-de-hacer-el-ascenso-de-colina-en-un-grafo)
Este el Código que me presento:

```
from pathlib import Path
import json
import random
from colorama import init, Fore
from tabulate import tabulate

#lista.pop(0)
def recorrer_grafo(BC_GRAFO, raiz, elem_buscar, cont = 0):
keys = list(BC_GRAFO.keys())
values = list(BC_GRAFO.values())
def avanza(raiz, elem_buscar, pos = 0, cont = 0, List_arb = [], i = 0):
    if raiz in keys:
        pos = keys.index(raiz)
        d = [ [raiz, values[pos], pos, elem_buscar]]
        print(Fore.YELLOW)
        print(tabulate(d,headers=["Raiz","Hijos","Poscicion","Elemento a buscar"]))
        print(Fore.RESET)
        if elem_buscar == keys[pos]:
            print("HA TERMINADO")
            return True
        if len(values[pos]) > 2:
            #COMPARA LOS VALORES
            if values[pos][0] < values[pos][2]:
                if len(List_arb) > 2:
                    #j = 0
                    #while j < 2:
                    List_arb.pop(0)
                    #    j += 1
                raiz = values[pos][1]
                List_arb.append(raiz)
                print("entro > 2")
                print("lista",List_arb)
                cont += 1
                i += 1
                avanza(raiz, elem_buscar,cont, List_arb=List_arb, i=i)
            else:
                elg = []
                a = 0
                long = len(values[pos])
                while a < long:
                    if a % 2 == 1:
                        elg.append(a)
                    a += 1
                print("################",elg)
                c = random.choice(elg)
                print("random",c)
                if  values[pos][c] in List_arb:
                    print("Volviendo a elegir")
                    elg.pop()
                    c = random.choice(elg)
                    print("random reelegido",c)

                if len(List_arb) > 2:
                    #j = 0
                    #while j < 2:
                    List_arb.pop(0)
                    #    j += 1
                raiz = values[pos][c]
                List_arb.append(raiz)
                print("lista",List_arb)
                cont += 1
                i += 1
                avanza(raiz, elem_buscar, cont, List_arb=List_arb, i=i)
        else:
            raiz = values[pos][1]
            if len(List_arb) > 2:
                #j = 0
                #while j < 2:
                List_arb.pop(0)
                #    j += 1
            List_arb.append(raiz)
            print("lista",List_arb)
            print("entro else")
            cont += 1
            i += 1
            avanza(raiz, elem_buscar,cont, List_arb=List_arb, i=i)
    else:
        print("Este elemento no esta en el grafo")
List_arb = []
List_arb.append(raiz)
i = 0
avanza(raiz, elem_buscar,cont, List_arb=List_arb, i=i)

def pedir_datos():
   raiz = str(input("Ingresa la raiz : \n"))
   elem_buscar = str(input("Ingresa el elemento a buscar : \n"))
   return raiz, elem_buscar

def main():
   #leer json
   JPATH = '.' #punto significa ruta actual
   JNAME = 'BC_GRAFO.json'

Ruta = Path(JPATH) / JNAME
if Ruta.exists():
    print("El archivo json existe")
    with Ruta.open() as archivojson: #abriendo solo como lectura
        BC_GRAFO = json.load(archivojson)
        keys = BC_GRAFO.keys()
        values = BC_GRAFO.values()
        print("KEYS:",keys)
        print("VALUES:",values)
        raiz, elem_buscar = pedir_datos()
        recorrer_grafo(BC_GRAFO, raiz, elem_buscar)
else:
    print("El archivo json no existe")

main()
```

Comment: El código está mal indentado, y no respeta las convenciones de Python ni las buenas prácticas de programación.

Comment: Bueno de eso código entiendo como la mitad ya que hay varias funciones donde no se ejecutan en el visual studio como el colorama y para que sirve la función o import tabulate?